# How to save plots automatically to png?

Tags: r, x11, graphic, rstudio-server

Is it possible that plots are automatically saved to a folder in `png` format in the following manner?

1. A new `png` file is created at each call of `plot.new()`
2. The file is updated at each update of graphics (when e.g. `points()`, `lines()`, `rect()` are called) so that whenever the plot is updated, the file is updated too (without having to close the device by `dev.off()`)

If this is possible, the following code should work as supposed:

```
plot(rnorm(100))
# create a new png file (e.g. plot-1.png) and the graphics is output to the file

plot(rnorm(100))
# create a new png file (e.g. plot-2.png) and the graphics is output to the file
abline(h = 0, col = "red")
# then the line is output to the file
```

The motivation of this is an attempt to avoid X11/Quartz forwarding (they do not play well with screen/tmux as the graphics are lost when user attaches the session from somewhere else), and to avoid `xpra` which there seems few people supporting it (causing Ubuntu 16.04 stuck at login screen, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/930161/ubuntu-16-04-2-cannot-login-after-installing-xpra?noredirect=1#comment1661998_930161).

It is quite like how RStudio Server handles R graphics (see source at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/tree/master/src/cpp/r/session/graphics). I'm wondering if there's an easier way to implement this (better not rewriting a graphic device from scratch)?

Comment: Before plotting, call function `png`. See `help("png")`. When you're done, `dev.off()`.

Comment: Check out [`rmote`](https://github.com/cloudyr/rmote), a tool I use periodically when I control R via ssh/emacs/ess and want to see my plots.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I mentioned that `png(...); plot(...); dev.off()` is not desired here since I want to capture *all* graphics created in the session without changing all my plot code into such style. Desired outcome is that for RStudio users, the plots are just fine, but for terminal users (e.g. emacs+ess), the plot should be automatically redirected to png files which are preserved no matter where I attach to the screen/tmux session.

Answer (score 4):

I'll quickly summarize how I use [`rmote`](https://github.com/cloudyr/rmote), though the github page has much more information.

1. `ssh -L 4321:localhost:4321 remoteuser@remotehost`
2. `tmux` (or `tmux attach` if already started)
3. `emacs`, start R using ESS
4. Once, to get things started:

   ```
   library(rmote)
   start_rmote(server_dir="path/to/save/pngs")
   ```
5. Make some plots, pointing your local web browser to `http://127.0.0.1:4321`. (Initially it'll show a directory listing, but once plots start it should auto-refresh.)

   ```
   plot(1:10, type='l')
   plot_done() # required for base-graphics
   plot(2:20)
   plot_done()
   library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() # no plot_done() required for ggplot2
   ```
6. Disconnect from tmux/ssh. (The web page will likely fail since the tunnel is closed.)
7. Reconnect, `ssh -L 4321:localhost:4321 remoteuser@remotehost` and `tmux attach`.
8. Refresh the browser, all plots available (with full history still)
9. When done, `stop_rmote()`. All plots are saved in `path/to/save/pngs/plots/`.

Bonus: if you do `start_rmote(...)` with the same directory, the same plot history will be available. So if you have to restart the R session, nothing has been lost. (I haven't tested it, but perhaps it'll work with simultaneous R sessions ...)

**EDIT**:

I often change the size of the plot, partly so I can fill the screen of my browser, but sometimes to set specific file sizes for reports or to replicate a different screen limitation.

```
options(rmote_device = list(type="png", retina=TRUE, width=1024, height=768))
```

Ref: https://github.com/cloudyr/rmote/blob/ee13936806cc1be5b2f95b70b33af374331ae2dc/man/rmote_device.Rd

**EDIT 2**: I guess I should note that, though perhaps under-utilizing the capabilities of `rmote`, it is certainly possible to use it *just* for the purposes of auto-PNG generation with most plotting methods. You don't have to connect to 127.0.0.1:4321 in order for the benefit of auto-saving PNGs to be realized.

Comment: Thanks! `plot_done()` is the very code that I mentioned is undesired which makes the script non-portable to RStudio users.

Comment: ... and, despite [everyone's wish](https://github.com/cloudyr/rmote/issues/3) and [best intentions](https://github.com/cloudyr/rmote/issues/2#issuecomment-192556281), it is still required for R base graphics works. In base graphics, every addition to the intended graphic results in a change to the canvas: `plot(...);lines(...);text(...)`. At what point is it "done"? With `ggplot2` (e.g.), the default method plots everything in one go, though you can circumvent that. With base graphics, that is not the case, so it is perfectly *unclear* when the intended plotting is complete.

Comment: I suspect it might be possible, though, to save each of these steps. Have you reached out to RStudio to ask them how they do it? Perhaps JJ could give you (and therefore others such as `rmote`) guidance on how to work around R's "-isms" with base graphics.